# If the linear regression coefficient of a/b is r, why is the linear regression coefficient of b/a 1/r?

Tags: regression, linear-regression

Consider two datasets of equal length: A and B.

Suppose, I find the linear regression equation between them as $$A = B * r1 + constant1$$
(I used Python functions: numpy.polyfit() or LinearRegression().fit().coef_. Both gave the same value)

This means, I could write $$B = A/r1 - constant1/r1 = A * r2 + constant2$$ where `r2 = 1/r1` and `constant2 = -constant1/r1`

But, when I find the linear regression coefficient between A and B in the opposite direction, I get $r2 \neq 1/r1$.

Particularly, when $r1 < 1$, I expect $r2 > 1$; even that isn't happening. In my project, I get $r1 = 0.75$, so I expect r2 to be 1.33, but I get $r2 = 0.89$ instead.

Note: When I make a scatterplot of A v/s B, and then if I switch it to B v/s A, I would expect the scatter to switch from one side of the 45$^\circ$ line to the other side. But here, both regression values make the scatter lie on the same side of the line.

Hope you people can help. Thanks!

Comment: the slopes are $\rho \frac{\sigma_A}{\sigma_B}$ and $\rho \frac{\sigma_B}{\sigma_A}$ where $\rho$ is the correlation between the data sets.  You only get the reciprocal when $\rho=\pm 1$ but usually it is smaller than that in magnitude

Comment: Thank you Henry! These formulae were exactly what I wanted. And obviously, they fit well with my regression coefficient values. Note: I don't know how to upvote a comment, or mark it as helpful.